# Is there such a thing as Localized Images for Cocos2dx?

Tags: iphone, localization

I wish to localize an iPhone game.

I understand that the text in the app can be automatically changed to different language. But how about an image?

Some of the text displayed in our app is in the form of an images.

Is there way we can get the app to display different images based on different locales.

Thanks.